# After bing search api subscription, How to get app id or app key?

Tags: api, bing-api

I want to use the Bing search api. **I have completed the developer registration, Then i have subscribed to the basic plan of bing search api** as per procedure.

I'm trying to get the App id or App key for bing search api. But i couldn't.

I read the procedure [in this bing search api link](http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx)

Hope someone will provide useful information.